# Datatables.net Deep Objects

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I'm following the deep objects example here: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html

and I can get everything running fine with the example data. However when trying to integrate my own data I'm having an issue. The given Ajax data format is:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Tiger Nixon"
    }
 ]
}
```

with the columns defined as:

```
"columns": [
   { "data": "name" }
]
```

My data has the same layout but I have a different root name

```
{
  "root": [
    {
      "name": "Tiger Nixon"
    }
 ]
}
```

with the columns defined as:

```
"columns": [
   { "root": "name" }
]
```

Is the "data" keyword fixed? Or is it just default and I need to reassign it somewhere?

The error I receive is: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" which I take to mean it can't find the object it's trying to get the property of.

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JSON data looks like:

```
{
  "root": [
    {
      "name": "Tiger Nixon"
    }
  ]
}
```

your DataTables initialization code should be:

```
$('#example').DataTables({
   'ajax' : {
      'url': '/server/script.php',
      'dataSrc': 'root'
   },
   'columns': [
      'data': 'name'
   ]
});
```

From the manual:

> As a string,
>   [ajax.dataSrc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc)
>   defines the property from the data source object (i.e. that returned
>   by the Ajax request) to read. It defaults to `data` property of the data 
>   source object (or `aaData` if `data` is not present for backwards 
>   compatibility).